# c# Creating unique keys from four numbers and checking duplicates

Tags: c#

I have a lot of lists of 4 numbers, `[0,1,2,1], [5,1,3,1], [0,1,2,0]. [0,1,2,1],`...
The lists contains duplicates.

I am gradually iterating the lists and checking if the same lists has already been iterated. In the upper case the first and last lists are the same.

Currently I am doing this by adding lists to HashSet :

```
HashSet<string> visited = new HashSet<string>();
string key = string.Joint(";", listOfNumbers);

if(visited.Contains(key)){
   dosomething...
   visited.Add(key);
}
```

I noticed that converting integers to string and checking if such string exists in hashset can be slow for large sets. If I use integers instead i.e. `int keys = (number1) * 1000000 + (number2) * 10000 + (number3) * 100 + (number4);` it becomes 1/3 faster, but this key in not necessary unique for large numbers.

I think, I am missing some basic knowledge for creating unique keys for a list of number and somehow checking the duplicates. Is there is a more efficient way than using strings to this problem?

Comment: How large can your numbers be? If it can be larger than a certain number, then there can be no unique key.

Comment: You're halfway towards understanding what `GetHashCode` is for, so do some more reading! The best solution would be to use a data structure which generates a suitable hash code for your array, without the cost of converting it to a string. A 4-element tuple would work (e.g. `HashSet<(int a, int b, int c, int d)>`), or a custom struct which wraps each 4-element array. Also don't use `.Contains` and then `.Add`: `.Add` returns a value saying whether the HashSet already contained the value, so use that

Comment: The whole hashcode system already has the logic for initially using a single int as the lookup, and then falling back to checking equality properly if you get two elements with the same int lookup.  This is what `HashSet<T>` is already doing. It's worth learning how to work with it properly.

Comment: That is why the IequalityComparer (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-5.0) has both a hash and a compare method.

Comment: In .NET 5 you can use `HashCode.Combine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<IList<T>>` to check for duplicate lists/arrays:

```
public class ListComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<IList<T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> _comparer;

    public ListComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals(IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
    {
        if(list1 == null && list2 == null) return true;
        if(list1 == null || list2 == null) return false;
        return list1.SequenceEqual(list2, _comparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IList<T> obj)
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach(T x in obj)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + _comparer.GetHashCode(x);
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this comparer in many LINQ methods, or in a dictionary(if you wanted to add the lists as a key) or use it in your `HashSet<T>`:

```
List<int[]> lists = new List<int[]>
{
    new[]{0,1,2,1}, new[]{5,1,3,1}, new[]{0,1,2,0}, new[]{0,1,2,1}
};

HashSet<IList<int>> visited = new HashSet<IList<int>>(new ListComparer<int>());
foreach(var arr in lists)
{
    if(!visited.Add(arr))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Duplicate detected: {string.Join(",", arr)}");
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

Outputs: `Duplicate detected: 0,1,2,1`

Comment: @PetrasVestartas: I just noticed a small issue and fixed it: use the comparer for `SequenceEqual`: `return list1.SequenceEqual(list2, _comparer);`. It would just have been an issue if you'd pass a custom comparer to this class because `GetHashCode` used it but not `Equals`.